# Javascript in Pentaho doesn't perform row by row operation?

Tags: javascript, pentaho

I have the following data:

[image]

I use this javascript:

```
var primary_phone ;
if (inter1.length == 10 && inter2.length == 10 && inter3.length == 0) {
    primary_phone = inter1;
}
else if (inter1.length == 10 && inter2.length == 10 && inter3.length == 10) {
    primary_phone = inter1;
}
else if (inter1.length != 10 && inter2.length == 10 && inter3.length == 0) {
    primary_phone = inter2;
}
else if (inter1.length != 10 && inter2.length != 10 && inter3.length != 10) {
    primary_phone = "+000000000000";
}
else if (inter1.length == 10 && inter2.length == 0 && inter3.length == 0) {
    primary_phone = inter1;
}
```

And what I get is:
[image]

Instead of:
[image]

Do you have an idea?

Comment: You can simplify your if statements greatly, for starters isolate tests that are common and test these together first...then in your inner test, test only for the diiferences.

Comment: @SPlatten, thank you for the comment, but do you think that's where the issue? For me, the issue is that the number got cascaded down.

Comment: @SPlatten, following your suggestion, simplified to and it worked. Do you have an idea why it was cascading down? :var primary_phone;

if ( inter1.length == 9 ) {
    primary_phone = inter1;
} else if ( inter1.length != 9 && inter2.length == 9 ) {
    primary_phone = inter2;
} else if ( inter3.length == 9 ) {
    primary_phone = inter3;
}
else {primary_phone = "+000000000000"}

Comment: Depending on the browser you are using you could use a debugger, set a break point on the first line and single step, that would help you understand why it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplified:

```
var primary_phone;

if ( inter1.length == 10 && (inter3.length == 0 || inter3.length == 10) {
    primary_phone = inter1;
} else if ( inter2.length == 10 && inter3.length == 0 ) {
    primary_phone = inter2;
} else if ( inter3.length != 10 ) {
    primary_phone = "+000000000000";
}
if ( primary_phone != undefined ) {
//primary_phone was assigned a value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript is not initialized per row, it (and the variables you assign) persists for the runtime of the transformation. In fact, you can have separate tabs for the start, per-row and end scripts.

To make it work, you need to set reset primary_phone either at the start of the script or in the else clause:

```
else { 
    primary_phone = null; 
}
```

Comment: A few years ago I talked to Matt Casters about Javascript in a Pentaho World event. He told me the reason why he recommend to avoid the use of Javascript step was precisely because the Rhino engine initializes the script for each row received, opposed to what you said.

Comment: I think the original java script step was replaced by a higher performing one at some point. Either way, it's easy to demonstrate that the variables persist.